Rounding a decimal to the nearest (up or down) 50's integer
I need to round a decimal to the nearest 50's (please correct this phrase because I am not sure how it's called in English)
For example:
1159 > 1150
499 > 500
324 > 300
201 > 200

This is what I did:
if ($number % 50 <= 25) { 
    $rounded_number = (int) (50 * floor($number / 50)); 
} else {
    $rounded_number = (int) (50 * ceil($number / 50)); 
}

Is it good? And maybe there's a better/neater way?

In your case you are looking to round up or down to the nearest 50.
However, if you simplify this to the nearest, say, 4 you would have the following map:
 0:  0 // 0
 1:  0 // 1
 2:  4 // 2
 3:  4 // 3
 4:  4 // 0
 5:  4 // 1
 6:  8 // 2
 7:  8 // 3
 8:  8 // 0
 9:  8 // 1
10: 12 // 2
11: 12 // 3
12: 12 // 0
13: 12 // 1
14: 16 // 2
...

The value of key % 4 is also added as a comment
You can see that if you applied your logic to this:
if ($number % 4 <= 2) { 
    $rounded_number = (int) (4 * floor($number / 4)); 
} else {
    $rounded_number = (int) (4 * ceil($number / 4)); 
}

when number=2 it would be set to 0.
Traditional rounding rules usually go up, and not down, at the half way point, but of course you can define what you want.
If you want to modify this to traditional rounding rules, use < instead of <= in your comparison.
There is a round() function in PHP (see here) so you could potentially use that directly and set,
$rounded_number = (int) (50 * round($number / 50));

